# Wanted data in a new line and no percentage % by using urllib

Tags: python, urllib

This can be tricky but apparently when I am pushing some parameters then I am getting the code in this format:

> clientport=9999&responsetime=2403&httpstatus=GOOD&serverIP=172.16.1.1&servicename=GET+%2Fqantas%2Fdom2%2Fprice&uniqueID=654901&clientip=172.16.1.1&endtime=2016-03-1+17%3A10%3A08&starttime=2016-03-1+17%3A08%3A08&httpstatuscode=200&serverport=9999&type=1

There is a specific format which the other end of the server understands and i want the data in this format where every paramter has new line with no % sign. How can we go about it

```
654901
1
172.16.1.1
9999
172.16.1.1
9999
GOOD
200
2016-03-1 17:08:08
2403
2016-03-1 17:10:08
GET /qantas/price
```

**The code which I am running**

```
import urllib
params = urllib.urlencode(
{'uniqueID': '654901',
'type': '1\n',
'clientip': '172.16.1.1',
'clientport': '9999',
'serverIP': '172.16.1.1',
'serverport': '9999',
'httpstatus': 'GOOD',
'httpstatuscode': '200',
'starttime': '2016-03-1 17:08:08',
'responsetime': '2403',
'endtime': '2016-03-1 17:10:08',
'servicename': 'GET /qantas/price'
})
print type(params)
f = urllib.urlopen("http://142.16.1.90:9111/TxnService", params)
print f.read()
print params
```

Comment: are you saying you just want the parameters on a new line without any %?

Comment: Yes, when i run the code then i should get everything in new line without % sign

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the requests module?

```
import requests

payload = {'uniqueID': '654901',
'type': '1\n',
'clientip': '172.16.1.1',
'clientport': '9999',
'serverIP': '172.16.1.1',
'serverport': '9999',
'httpstatus': 'GOOD',
'httpstatuscode': '200',
'starttime': '2016-03-1 17:08:08',
'responsetime': '2403',
'endtime': '2016-03-1 17:10:08',
'servicename': 'GET /qantas/price'
}

r = requests.post("http://142.16.1.90:9111/TxnService", data = payload)
print(r.text)
```

Comment: let me try and i will get back to you.